# vb.net compability in newer visual studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I program in vb.net language using Visual studio sometimes (I am not a professional). Currently I am using visual studio 2010, and I am thinking about updating to Visual studio 2013 or Visual Studio 2015.

Do you know if vb.net is supported in VS 2013 and/or 2015?

I am asking this because here in Brazil, all Vb.net courses I found are using Visual Studio 2010 yet, and in C# for example, it is already used Visual studio 2013.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer, yes it is.  In fact you can now get the fully featured visual studio community edition for free and the 2015 version supports the new 'Roslyn' features added to vb.

Comment: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx  use desktop version for VB.Net